# Reading registry values with cmake

Tags: cmake, registry

On a Windows 7 machine I cannot read any registry values that contain a semicolon.

For example if you have 7-zip, running the following

```
SET(MYPATH  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\7-Zip;Path])
MESSAGE("MYPATH = ${MYPATH}")
```

results in

```
MYPATH = [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\7-Zip;Path]
```

instead of the actual path as per the following [thread](http://www.mail-archive.com/cmake@cmake.org/msg19014.html). I think cmake support for registry paths that contain ";" are broken on Windows 7. Can somebody confirm this? Is there any work-around?

Comment: This is why I consider that using a build system that use a common scripting language is a much better solution. I'm thinking at solution like Waf (Python) or Rake (Ruby).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[According to the wiki](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#How_can_I_get_a_windows_registry_key_.3F), you can't use `SET` to view the value of a registry key. The registry value is only read when you do some cache operation on it. For example, the following should output the path you want:

```
GET_FILENAME_COMPONENT(MYPATH "[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\7-Zip;Path]"
                       ABSOLUTE CACHE)
MESSAGE("MYPATH = ${MYPATH}")
```

Comment: Just to note, it seems to me CMake cannot read REG_DWORD values. It's able only to read strings?