# Reading registry values using CMake

Tags: oracle, cmake, registry

I did a lot of research on the Internet, but I couldn't solve my problem.

For our Windows build environment we need the Oracle client. There is no environment variable that contains the path to ORACLE_HOME. But in the registry there is this path, as described [here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_windows_multiple_registry_entries.htm).

As far as I found out, CMake can also read the registry. This has already been asked here on Stackoverflow. But in my environment this doesn't work and I run out of ideas.

First I tried the *set* command. But that doesn't work anymore.

```
set(ora_set "[HKLM\\SOFTWARE\\ORACLE\\KEY_OraClient12Home1\\ORACLE_HOME]")
message( "ora_set (set) = ${ora_set}" )
```

Output:

```
ora_set (set) = [HKLM\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_OraClient12Home1\ORACLE_HOME]
```

I expected to get `<Path to ORACLE_HOME>`, but I've got `<[HKLM\\SOFTWARE\\ORACLE\\KEY_OraClient12Home1\\ORACLE_HOME]>`.

Then I tried *get_filename_component*, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762201/reading-registry-values-with-cmake) on StackOverflow:

```
get_filename_component(ora_gfc "[HKLM\\SOFTWARE\\ORACLE\\KEY_OraClient12Home1\\ORACLE_HOME]" ABSOLUTE CACHE)
message( "ora_gfc (get_filename_component) = ${ora_gfc}" )
```

Output:

```
ora_gfc (get_filename_component) = <Path to ORACLE_HOME>[HKLM/SOFTWARE/ORACLE/KEY_OraClient12Home1/ORACLE_HOME]
```

I expected to get `<Path to ORACLE_HOME>`, but I've got `<Path to ORACLE_HOME[HKLM\\SOFTWARE\\ORACLE\\KEY_OraClient12Home1\\ORACLE_HOME]>`. CMake always appended the registry path to the value from the registry. I couldn't find a way to prevent this.

As a third possibility I tried *execute_process*, because with reg query you can also read the registry from batch as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19581078/when-querying-the-registry-from-a-batch-file-can-i-query-the-data).

```
execute_process (
    COMMAND FOR /F "usebackq tokens=3*" %%A IN (`REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\ORACLE\\KEY_OraClient12Home1" /v ORACLE_HOME`) DO ECHO %%A
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE ora_exp
)
message( "ora_exp (execute_process) = ${ora_exp}" )
```

Output:

```
ora_exp (execute_process) =
```

I expected to get `<Path to ORACLE_HOME>`, but I've got an empty variable. CMake doesn't seem to like that either, allthough the batch command works as expected in a separate batch file.

Now I'm lost: How to read the registry value correctly with CMake. Does anyone have a hint?

My environment is

- Windows 10 64-bit
- CMake 3.12.4
- Oracle Client 12.2.0.1

Comment: Try this, so far detects only XE installation, but it should be possible to extend it.
https://github.com/tora-tool/tora/blob/master/cmake/modules/FindOracle.cmake

Comment: @ibre5041 thanks for your hint. I've noted that in the file you mentioned every CMake part was written in uppercase. As I tried in my script to have all in uppercase except the key, everything works.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be two things going on.  You cannot use set to just read the registry.
https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/FAQ#how-can-i-get-a-windows-registry-key-

`GET_FILENAME_COMPONENT(test_set  "[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\VisualStudio\\14.0\\VC\\Runtimes\\debug\\x64;Version]" ABSOLUTE CACHE)
message( "test_set (set) = ${test_set}" )`

prints:
`test_set (set) = C:/Users/XXX/v14.14.26405.00`

Also note the format of the key.  It probably should be:
`[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\ORACLE\\KEY_OraClient12Home1;ORACLE_HOME]`

It also only works on certain kinds of registry key types or it will just return `/registry`.

Comment: Thx for hint. As mentioned above, the common thing of your proposal and of ibre5041s are uppercase statements. Using uppercase, it works. Independent of the format of the key. Even with HKLM instead of HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE works like a charme.

Answer (score 0):

This question maybe a bit old, still.

Since CMake 2.24 you can use [cmake_host_system_information](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/cmake_host_system_information.html) to query Windows registry.